# Can I override and use a subclass for the template type in as the super class

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Can I override and use a subclass for the template type in as the super class.

I'm a Java programmer and this works well with generics however I am unfamiliar with how to do much in C++

can I use a class

```
template <typename T>
class A{
public:
    T get(){
        return t;
    }
    A(){
    }
    void set(T tt){
        t=tt;
    }
private: 
    T t;
};
```

And extend it with something similar to

```
class B:A<B>
```

Where subclass B is used as generic type for class A and class B requires no generics

Comment: You're making a `class Box { Box b; };`. Only Professor Farnsworth is allowed to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle, your usage of templates is called "Curiously recurring template pattern" (CRTP) and perfectly valid.

However, be aware that Java generics and C++ templates are very different at very many points, including the limitations on the use of B in A. Derived CRTP classes are incomplete at template instantiation, so you can't allocate any objects of them in the base class like you did. That is the reason your **code doesn't compile**. The usual method is instead to cast in the accessor methods, like:

```
 void set(T tt){
    static_cast<T&>(*this)=tt;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

yes:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern